# Python 3 : Two or more tuples as arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, tuples

Is it possible to unpack two tuples as an argument of a function in Python 3?

The code goes like this...

```
def fun(*tuple1, *tuple2):
    #some code to compare elements of tuple1 to elements of tuple2
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you *could* do that, how would you decide which args from `fun(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` went to which tuple?

Comment: You might be thinking of something Python 2 allowed: `def fun((x0, x1), (y0, y1)): ...`, after which a call like `fun(t1, t2)` would unpack the two tuples for you. This was removed from Python 3 to simplify function definitions, forcing you to unpack the tuples explicitly in the body of the function.

Comment: If you are looking to compare two tuples element-wise, `zip` is your friend: `for x, y in zip(t1, t2): ...` lets you operate on `t1[0]` and `t2[0]`, then `t1[1]` and `t2[1]`, then `t1[2]` and `t2[2]`, and so on. The assignment performed by the `for` loop does the unpacking for you while iterating over the two tuples in parallel.

Comment: Ooh! Thank you! I'd surely try to use the zip function!

Answer (score 0):

Nope, because it would be ambiguous to determine where the first tuple ends and the second tuple begins.

There are two work-arounds:

You can just take in two tuples directly:

```
def fun(tulpe1, tuple2):
    # compare tuple1 to tuple2
```

Alternatively, you can take in multiple tuples as kwargs:

```
def fun(**tuples):
    # for tuple in tuples:
    #     do some stuff
```